# Create a table like structure with keys on the left and values on the right of the table from json data and display on html using python flask

Tags: python, json, flask, html-table

I am trying to create a table like structure where this table has two columns ( specs, value) and all the keys go into specs column and values for those keys go into value column. I have a json file locally stored on my system. So, the goal is to get everything from that json file and create this table structure and display it on my webpage.

Here is my route for Specs. When users click on a button thats in my html page, that button basically runs this function where it fetches the hosts facts, and stores that json data in a file called hostsfacts.json. I want to be able to create a table I described above from that json data and pass that table to provision.html.

```
@app.route('/Specs', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def Specs():
ID = request.form["foremanId1"]
print(ID)
response10 = requests.get('https://test.com/api/hosts/{v1}/facts'.format(v1=ID), auth=('abc', 'password'), verify=False)
if response10.status_code == 200:
    myDictForHostsFacts = json.loads(response10.content.decode('utf-8'))
    resultForHostsFacts = json.dumps(myDictForHostsFacts)

with open("static\hostsFacts.json", "w") as hostsFactsFile:
    add_text1 = (resultForHostsFacts)
    print(add_text1, file=hostsFactsFile)
    hostsFactsFile.close()

return render_template('provision.html')
```

here is my json file:

```
{"total": 366, "subtotal": 1, "page": 1, "per_page": 320, "search": " host = 529", "sort": {"by": null, "order": null}, "results": {"mac7287327223": {"memory::system": null, "dmi::board": null, "disks::sdb::size_bytes": "0", "nmprimary_ipv4_dns-priority": "0", "nmprimary_ipv6_dns-priority": "0", "nmprimary_802-3-ethernet_speed": "0", "nmprimary_ipv4_route-table": "0", "nmprimary_ipv6_route-table": "0", "dmi::bios::release_date": "03/08/2022", "bios_release_date": "03/08/2022", "disks::sdb::size": "0 bytes", "partitions::/dev/loop2::size": "1.56 GiB", "partitions::/dev/mapper/live-rw::size": "1.56 GiB", "partitions::/dev/mapper/live-base::size": "1.56 GiB", "partitions::/dev/loop4::size": "1.56 GiB", "processorcount": "16", "processors::count": "16", "nmprimary_dhcp4_option_expiry": "1661435487", "partitions::/dev/loop2::size_bytes": "1677721600", "partitions::/dev/mapper/live-rw::size_bytes": "1677721600", "partitions::/dev/loop4::size_bytes": "1677721600"}}}
```

So, I just want to create table with whats inside of mac7287327223{}. I am looking to have something like this table below:

### |    Specs            |    value  |

|    memory::system   |   null    |

---

|    dmi::board       |   null    |

---

|    disks::sdb::size |   0 bytes |

---

|    processorcount   |   16      |

I was having hard time to format this table here in stackoverflow so, I just put it like this to give everyone an idea.

In case if you want to look at provision.html, it is super simple because all i want is to display this table there. So, all it would have is body tag with the table inside it. That's all.

So, I am basically trying to achieve this and I have been having really hard time figuring out this issue since I really need to use python for this.

Please help me if you can. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to store the data in a .json file unless you want to save it permanently.

In Flask you can pass data to the `render_template()` function:

```py
if response10.status_code == 200:
    myDictForHostsFacts = json.loads(response10.content.decode('utf-8'))
    # ...
    return render_template('provision.html', data=myDictForHostsFacts)
```

In your HTML you can then access that dictionary with the jinja2 syntax. Jinja2 is a templating tool which basically allows you to use python code in your html-document

```html
<table class="table table-dark">
    <thead class="thead thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <!-- Your Columns HERE -->
        <th class="header text-left" scope="col">Key</th>
        <th class="header text-left" scope="col">Value</th>
    
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="temp-table">
      {% for entry in data%}
      <tr>
        <td class="text-left">{{entry}}</td>
        <td class="text-left">{{data[entry]}}</td>
       
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

The HTML-Code above is some of my own code which I edited. I recommend a look at the [documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/) of jinja2 it is quite useful.

Comment: I understand this process here. But, what do I put in {{ entry }}. I am assuming I put a key there. If you look at the json file I have mac7287327223{} as key which has numerous keys inside it. The problem I am having is, I am not being able to fetch those key inside mac7287327223{} and their respective values and I cannot hardcode it because they keys might change for other hosts facts. How do I display those keys that are inside mac7287327223{} on left and their respective values on right? Thanks for the help

Comment: Right now, its giving me all the keys and values in a table on my html page indeed but I only need to display keys and value that are inside mac7287327223{} and that is the problem I am getting into.

Comment: Well then your question is acutally about how to parse that JSON you get from that web-page. I suggest you do that in the backend so that whatever data you pass in `render_template(html_file, data=data)` can be easily accessed from Jinja. I suggest you either edit or open a new question.

Comment: I think that was my initial question because I wanted to create a table as I have shown above. My wording might have been different. Do you happen to know how to do that using jinja?

Comment: I dont know the exact answer but I would try to search through the whole dict with a regular expression für your macxxxx or whatever the important key will be. And then just send this dict to the frontend. The jinja-code should stay more or less the same. You should filter the dict in your backend